# Low quality answer guideline

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

I was going through some of the posts in the low quality posts list and was shown [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9781394/829571):

- it is not incorrect, but
- it does not bring any value for future users (whether the whole question/answers does is probably also questionable!)
- there are 4 other answers that give more or less the same information in a more detailed way
- the user did not gain rep and probably never will out of this answer

I would tend to recommend deletion as it seems like useless noise to me.

What main criteria should I take into account for a deletion recommendation?